# Can I directly send phone number via POST in REST API?

Tags: rest, post

I am an university student and now developing my own web project.
I have an input box to put phone number, and I get its value and send it to server through POST in REST API.
I am worried about sending a personal information without any security processing.

Is it okay to just sending it through POST? Or Is there any security-related library that I can use?

Comment: Use https. There’s nothing more you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Https protocal with enable TLS (1.1 or 1.2). Then should be ok. With this, it will ensure form data security at transport layer (from client app to backend app via Internet).